# How to limit a user description to a certain amount of characters in a user list?

Tags: wordpress, metadata

I'm changing the layout of my "users" page in a Wordpress website [here](http://wordsinthebucket.com/contributors)

I would like to limit the numbers of characters of the description to a certain amount, in order to "equalize" the bio of each author (user).

Is it possible?

Here the template code:

```html
 <?php

/*
Template Name: Display Contributors and Authors
*/

    $args = array(
         'role'    => 'contributor',
         'orderby' => 'post_count',
         'order'   => 'DESC'
    );
    $contributors = get_users( $args );

    ?>
    
<?php get_header();?>
<div id="main">
<div id="primary" class="three-parts archive">
<div class="widget-title">
  <?php the_title(); ?>
</div>
 <div id="blog-list" class="blog-category">
 <ul> 
  <?php

  foreach($contributors as $contributor) 
 
  {
  
  ?>
  <li style="margin-top: 10px; width:25%;"> 
   <div class="blog-post-image">
    <div class="image_fx5">
     <a href=<?php echo get_author_posts_url( $contributor->ID ); ?>><?php echo get_avatar( $contributor->user_email, '128' ); ?></a>
    </div>
   </div>
    <!--author-image-->
    <div class="blog-post-title-box">
     <div class="blog-post-title">
     <h2>
     <a href=<?php echo get_author_posts_url( $contributor->ID ); ?>><?php echo $contributor->display_name; ?></a>
     </h2>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!--author-name-->
     <div class="blog-post-content" style="padding-bottom: 0px; text-align: justify;">
     <?php echo $contributor->description; ?>
     </div>
     <div id="author-info" style="margin-top: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px;">
     <div id="author-desc" style="width: 100%;">
     <ul class="author-social" style="padding-top: 0px;">
     <?php if($contributor->facebook) { ?>
     <li style="
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    height: 25px;
">
      <a href="http://facebook.com/<?php echo $contributor->facebook; ?>" class="fb-social-icon" target="_blank">
      </a>
     </li>
     <?php } ?>
     <?php if($contributor->twitter) { ?>
     <li style="
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    height: 25px;
">
      <a href="https://twitter.com/<?php echo $contributor->twitter; ?>" class="twitter-social-icon" target="_blank">
      </a>
     </li>
     <?php } ?>
     <?php if($contributor->google) { ?>
     <li style="
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    height: 25px;
">
      <a href="http://plus.google.com/<?php echo $contributor->google; ?>?rel=author" class="google-social-icon" target="_blank">
      </a>
     </li>
     <?php } ?>
     <?php if($contributor->pinterest) { ?>
     <li style="
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    height: 25px;
">
      <a href="http://www.pinterest.com/<?php echo $contributor->pinterest; ?>?rel=author" class="pinterest-social-icon" target="_blank">
      </a>
     </li>
     <?php } ?>
     <?php if($contributor->instagram) { ?>
     <li style="
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    height: 25px;
">
      <a href="http://www.instagram.com/<?php echo $contributor->instagram; ?>?rel=author" class="instagram-social-icon" target="_blank">
      </a>
     </li>
     <?php } ?>
     </ul>
     </div>
     </div>
     <!--author-desc-->
  </li>
   <?php } ?>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
  <!--primary-->
 <div id="secondary">
  <?php if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Category Sidebar')): endif; ?>
 </div>
 <!--secondary-->
</div>
<!--main-->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean the description try...

```
<?php echo substr($contributor->description, 0, strpos($contributor->description, ' ', 150)); ?>
```

Which will return 150 (you can change this to what you like) characters and also make sure it finishes the last word as well.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you Simon.